# Implementing parseInt method

Tags: java, parseint

relevant code:

```
 while (true) {
      String s = input.next();

      if (s.equals("done!")) {
        break;
      }
      int i = parseInt(s);
      taking.add(i);
    }
```

basically I have a while loop that adds the number they type in to the array list taking. I want the loop to end if the person types in "done!" so I'm receiving what they type in as a string in order to check for that first. Otherwise it should add the number so i'm using the parseInt method but I get the error message:

```
Generate.java:26: error: cannot find symbol
      int i = bitCount(s);
              ^
  symbol:   method bitCount(String)
  location: class Generate
1 error
```

Comment: error message says that `bitCount(String)` is not reachable in class Generate. Is `bitCount(String)` declared in another method?

Comment: Your problem is outside the code you post (you have no "int i = bitCount(String)" anywhere) - will remove downvote if you edit question to show the relevant line.

Comment: Try to post all your code

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `Integer.parseInt(s)` instead of `parseInt(s)` like this:

```
 int i = Integer.parseInt(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting confused with `parseInt(String)` function belongs to `javascript`. but here you are using `java` which is not a scripting but having a `OOPS` concept so, Whenever you try to access a method Outside of `class` you need either `object.methodName(parameters...)` (if instance methods) or `ClassName.methodName(parameters...)`(If method is static).

**Here** , `Integer` class contains a **static** method `parseInt(String args)` , and you are calling `parseInt(String args)` method outside of class

So Correct Way of Calling this method is

```
   int a= Integer.parseInt(String args);
```